# No code coverage in functional test with Codeception and C3

Tags: symfony, unit-testing, automated-tests, codeception

I've written a basic functional test in Codeception and I'm not seeing any coverage in either the HTML or XML reports. The pass/fail reports are generated correctly.

```
<?php

class MyFirstCest {
  public function _before(FunctionalTester $I) {
  }

  public function _after(FunctionalTester $I) {
  }

  // tests
  public function tryToTestLoginPage(FunctionalTester $I) {
    $I->amOnPage('/app/login/');
    $I->seeInSource('html');
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
There was 1 failure:

---------
1) MyFirstCest: Try to test login page
 Test  tests\functional\MyFirstCest.php:tryToTestLoginPage
 Step  See in source "html"
 Fail  Failed asserting that  on page /app/login/
--> #!/usr/bin/env php
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined offset:
[Content too long to display. See complete response in 'C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\tests/_output\' directory]
--> contains "html".
```

The error occurs in `codecept.phar`, but I assume other people are able to use the same version (2.3.6) without errors.

`codeception.yml`:

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
settings:
    shuffle: true
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
coverage:
    enabled: true
    blacklist:
        include:
            - tests\*
    low_limit: 0
    high_limit: 50
    c3_url: 'http://localhost'
#    remote: true
```

`functional.suite.yml`:

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration
#
# Suite for functional tests
# Emulate web requests and make application process them
# Include one of framework modules (Symfony2, Yii2, Laravel5) to use it
# Remove this suite if you don't use frameworks

actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost'
            auth: ['admin', '123345']
            curl:
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true
            cookies:
                cookie-1:
                    Name: userName
                    Value: john.doe
                cookie-2:
                    Name: authToken
                    Value: 1abcd2345
                    Domain: subdomain.domain.com
                    Path: /admin/
                    Expires: 1292177455
                    Secure: true
                    HttpOnly: false
coverage:
    enabled: true
```

I'm running Codeception with:

```
php codecept.phar run --html report.html --coverage-html coverage --xml report.xml --coverage-xml coverage.xml functional
```

The output file says: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in phar://C:/usr/bin/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Command/Self‌​Update.php on line 44`, which indicates a Codeception error, however, I'm sure other people get this to work without causing errors in Codeception, so I assume I've got a configuration error somewhere.

Comment: Look at C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\tests\_output directory and find html file with name matching your test name, then look at it and try to understanding. There is an obvious beginning of PHP Notice in provided output, what does the full notice message say?

Comment: @Naktibalda I'm not at work at the moment, but from memory it was completely blank. I've also created an issue on Github, with more info about PHP error messages (rather than Codeception error messages) which you may have already seen.

Comment: @Naktibalda It was the directory that was created but completely empty. The file says `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in phar://C:/usr/bin/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Command/SelfUpdate.php on line 44`, the same error I reported on Github. I believe these are two separate issues. Codeception shouldn't crash there (Github) and my configuration seems to be wrong (Stack Overflow).